# Unable to print a List of object that contains in another List of object

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I have the following Model in my project

**Animal**

```
private name: string;
private age: string;  
private zooLocation: Zoo[];
```

**Zoo**

```
private zooname: string;
private zooaddress: address;
```

In the project `data` returns `Animal[]`. So data contains a list of animal objects. All I want is to `console.log()` all the zoo locations that are available. So the `Animal` object may have around 10 objects in it, where each object may contain more than one `Zoo` locations.

All I want to do is to print all of these `Zoo` location that belongs to the `Animal` object.

What I tried so far:

```
this.animalList = data;

this.allZooLocation = this.animalList.zooLocation;
```

`this.animalList.zooLocation;` shows an error

> Property ' zooLocation  ' does not exist on type ' Animal  []'

Comment: Error is so clear that you are trying to access property on an array and not on object. It should be like `this.animalList[0].zooLocation`

Answer (score 2):

That is because the `this.animalList` is an array and don't have `zooLocation` property.
You can loop in the `animalList` and get the data from each element of that those are in type of `Animal`. Something like this:

```
for (let animal of this.animalList) {
  console.log(animal.zooLocation);
}
```

This code prints `zooLocation` of each animal in the console. If you like do something else to that locations, you can replace your code with `console.log`.

Comment: What if I only want to print  zooname. So console.log(animal.zooLocation.zooname); didnt work.

Comment: It don't work because similar to `animalList`, `zooLocation` is an array of elements with `Zoo` type. so You should do something like I did for `animalList`.

Answer (score 0):

The animalList is basically an array and not a json. While this 'dot' notation works in a JSON format, the array still needs a location to point out to.

For example, animalList[0] represents the object at the first location of the list and so on. So, what you want to print is animalList[i].zooLocation where i will vary from 0 to (arrayLength-1).

You can use a normal for loop for this. ex:

```
for(let i=0; i<animalList.length; i++){
 console.log(animalList[i].zooLocation);}
```

Alternatively, there are various other ways to parse data in typescript array like a for each loop or by using

`for(let animal of animalList){
console.log(animal)
}`

Comment: What if I only want to print  zooname. So console.log(animal.zooLocation.zooname); didnt work.

Answer (score 0):

This is my answer,

```
public AnimalList : Animal[] = [
    {
      name : 'name1',
      age : "20",
      zooLocation : [
        { zooname : "zooname1",
          zooaddress : "zooaddress1"
        },
        { zooname : "zooname2",
          zooaddress : "zooaddress2"
        },
        { zooname : "zooname3",
          zooaddress : "zooaddress3"
        },
      ]
    },
    {
      name : 'name2',
      age : "21",
      zooLocation : [
        { zooname : "zooname4",
          zooaddress : "zooaddress4"
        },
        { zooname : "zooname5",
          zooaddress : "zooaddress5"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

In template,

```
<div *ngFor="let list of AnimalList">
  <div>{{list.name}}</div> 
  <div *ngFor="let item of list.zooLocation">
    {{item.zooname}}
    {{item.zooaddress}} 
  </div>
</div>
```

Result

```
name1
zooname1 zooaddress1
zooname2 zooaddress2
zooname3 zooaddress3
name2
zooname4 zooaddress4
zooname5 zooaddress5
```

or you can use this in your .ts

```
for(let j=0; j<this.AnimalList.length; j++){
     console.log(this.AnimalList[j].zooLocation);
}
```